# How can I convert an animate PNG to GIF keeping animate?

Tags: javascript, php, imagemagick, animated-gif, apng

how do i convert animate apng to gif keep animate by php?

i saw the PHP: imagegif - Manual like that but the output gif is without animate

```
$png = imagecreatefrompng('./X.png');
imagegif($png, './php.gif');
?>
```

wish it can keep the animate

Comment: PNGs aren't usually animated. APNGs are, but GD [probably doesn't support them](https://libgd.github.io/manuals/2.2.5/files/gd_png-c.html).

Comment: i think it work by someway like
1.https://ezgif.com/apng-to-gif
2.https://www.aconvert.com/image/apng-to-gif/

Comment: Use imagemagick instead.

Comment: Thank you!Now i'm using imagemagick ,but i don't know how to do QAQ?